# Instantiate swift class which conforms protocol, to call protocol's method from another class

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have protocol:

```
protocol ConnectionServerProtocol {
    func connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username: String, password: String)
}
```

I have class which conforms this protocol:

```
public class ConnectionServer: NSObject {
    var username: String?
    var password: String?
    let connectionServerProtocol: ConnectionServerProtocol

    public init(connectionServerProtocol: ConnectionServerProtocol) {
        self.connectionServerProtocol = connectionServerProtocol
    }
}
```

I have method in that class:

```
public func connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username: String, password: String) {

    self.username = username
    self.password = MD5(password)
    self.connectionServerProtocol.dataTask()
}
```

And I call this method inside ConnectionServer class like this:

```
self.connectionServerProtocol.connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username:"someUserName", password: "SomePassword")
```

I have another class  - ViewController, and Q is - how I can instantiate(or not) ConnectionServer to call  `connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username: "someUserName", password: "SomePassword")` from ViewController class?

I was trying to instantiate ConnectionServer many different ways.

If I do:

```
let cs = ConnectionServer()
```

I got: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ConnectionServer' with no arguments" (obviously).

If I do:

```
let cs = ConnectionServer(connectionServerProtocol:ConnectionServerProtocol)
```

I got: "Argument type 'ConnectionServerProtocol.Protocol' does not conform to expected type 'ConnectionServerProtocol' Insert ' as! ConnectionServerProtocol'" (also obviously)

If I insert:

```
let cs = ConnectionServer(connectionServerProtocol: ConnectionServerProtocol.self as! ConnectionServerProtocol)
```

I got: "Could not cast value of type 'SwiftCommons.ConnectionServerProtocol.Protocol' (0x10367dcb0) to 'SwiftCommons.ConnectionServerProtocol'"

If I do:

```
let cs = ConnectionServer.self
cs.connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username: SomeUserName", password:"SomePassword")
```

I got: "Instance member 'connectWithUsernameAndPassword' cannot be used on type 'ConnectionServer'"

Please help.

UPD:
I refactored:

```
public class ConnectionServer: NSObject, ConnectionServerProtocol {
}
```

Now it is conforms to a protocol. I should explain more, sorry for inconvenience. Implementation of ConnectionServer and ConnectionServerProtocol are inside of my Swift Framework, and I'm trying to call

```
cs.connectWithUsernameAndPassword(username: SomeUserName", password:"SomePassword")
```

from outside of that framework.

Comment: _"I have class wich conforms this protocol:"_ No, you don't. You haven't declared conformance.

Comment: OK, if I change declaration like this: public class ConnectionServer: NSObject, ConnectionServerProtocol, does it make any differences affecting my Q or possible answer?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the protocol's metatype? You need to pass an instance of some type that conforms to the protocol, not the protocol metatype.

Comment: You are confused. Your `ConnectionServer` class doesn't conform to your `ConnectionServerProtocol`. It contains an object that conforms to that protocol. It might make sense to refactor your code so your `ConnectionServer` class DOES conform to your protocol, but you're going to have to tell us more about what you're trying to do before we can help you.

Comment: I did, how I got: public class ConnectionServer: NSObject, ConnectionServerProtocol. What difference does it make? Can I now call desired method from another class?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka could you show example, how can I achieve it?